# ASP.NET Sum a column returned from stored procedure in LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, linq

Okay, so this probably a really simple problem which I am having an unbelievably difficult time coming up with a solution to.

I have a simple ASP.Net web application which submits and retrieves capital projects to/from a SQL Server database, based upon a property selected by the user.

In this project, I have a number of stored procedures built in SQL Server that handle the data transfers from the application to the database. I am using LINQ in the ASP.NET project to connect to the stored procedures.

In particular, I have an ASP.NET `Repeater` set up that is a populated list of all submitted Capital Projects for the selected company. My code is rather simple:

The repeater:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptProjects" runat="server" OnItemCommand="rptProjects_ItemCommand">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table style="table-layout:auto; width:100%">
            <tr>
                <td style="width:2%"><b>Item #</b></td>
                <td style="width:2%"><b>Priority</b> </td>
                <td style="width:10%"><b>Project Name</b></td>
                <td style="width:20%"><b>Description</b></td>
                <td style="width:4%"><b>Reason</b></td>
                <td style="width:3%"><b>Category</b></td>
                <td style="width:2%"><b>Asset Age</b></td>
                <td style="width:3%"><b>Est. Useful Life</b></td>
                <td style="width:2%"><b>Qty</b></td>
                <td style="width:2%"><b>Unit Type</b></td>
                <td style="width:3%"><b>Unit Cost</b></td>
                <td style="width:3%"><b>Total Budget</b></td>
                <td style="width:20%"><b>Owner Comments</b></td>
                <td style="width:3%">&nbsp</td>
                <td style="width:3%">&nbsp</td>
            </tr>
         </table>
     </HeaderTemplate>
     <ItemTemplate>
         <table style="width:100%">
             <tr>
                 <td style="width:2%">R#</td>
                 <td style="width:2%"><%#Eval("Priority") %> </td>
                 <td style="width:10%"><%#Eval("ProjectName") %></td>
                 <td style="width:20%"><%#Eval("Description") %> </td>
                 <td style="width:4%"><%#Eval("Reason") %> </td>
                 <td style="width:3%"><%#Eval("Category") %></td>
                 <td style="width:2%"><%#Eval("AssetAge") %> </td>
                 <td style="width:3%"><%#Eval("AssetUsefulLife") %></td>
                 <td style="width:2%"><%#Eval("Quantity") %> </td>
                 <td style="width:2%"><%#Eval("UnitType") %></td>
                 <td style="width:3%"><%#Eval("UnitCost", "{0:C0}") %></td>
                 <td style="width:3%"><%#Eval("TotalAmount", "{0:C0}") %></td>
                 <td style="width:20%"><%#Eval("OwnerNotes") %></td>
                 <td style="width:3%">
                     <asp:Button ID="btnDelete" runat="server" Text="X" 
                          ToolTip="Delete the selected project." 
                          CommandName="Delete" CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ItemCode") %>' 
                          CausesValidation="False" />
                 </td>
                 <td style="width:3%">
                     <asp:Button ID="btnUpdate" runat="server" Text="Edit" 
                          ToolTip="Update the selected project." 
                          CommandName="Update" CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ItemCode") %>' 
                          CausesValidation="False" />
                 </td>
             </tr>
         </table>
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

The repeater is populated very simply in C# using a dataContext which executes a stored procedure that returns all projects for the property.

The C# code:

```
//Load any projects submitted for the property
using(var dataContext = new CAPEXDataConnDataContext())
{
   rptProjects.DataSource = dataContext.web_CAPEXProjectsByCompany(Session["PropertyNumber"].ToString());
   rptProjects.DataBind();
}
```

This results in a nice, simple repeater:

[image: ASP Repeater]

My question is: within the context of the current code, how can I easily sum the total budget column into a `FooterTemplate` in the repeater?

I am not sure if this is necessary or not, but I am building on the .NET 4.5 framework.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, I hope you can do by providing direction;

1. Add a `FooterTemplate` and a `Label` inside it
2. Implement `ItemDataBound` on `Repeater` control
3. Using below condition sum values

> ```
> protected void repeater_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
>     {
>         if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Footer)
>         {
>            //Write your logic to retrieve each value from the collection    
>            //YourRepeaterName.Items and add it to Label at the end
>         }
>     }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Define a global variable in C# and sum in it in `ItemDataBound` handler. Something like this.

```
decimal grandTotal = 0;
//...
using(var dataContext = new CAPEXDataConnDataContext())
{
   rptProjects.DataSource = dataContext.web_CAPEXProjectsByCompany(Session["PropertyNumber"].ToString());
   grandTotal = 0;
   rptProjects.DataBind();
}
//...
protected void rptProjects_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
   if(e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
   {
      grandTotal += (decimal)e.Item.DataItem["TotalAmount"];
   }
   if(e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Footer)
   {
      ((Literal)e.Item.FindControl("grandTotal")).Text = grandTotal.ToString("C");
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, on the line `grandTotal +=(decimal)e.Item.DataItem["TotalAmount"];` I am getting an error that states `Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object'`

Comment: Change to`(decimal)((DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem)["..."]` or whatever type of your `dataSource` returns.

Comment: Now this: `unable to cast object of type '_2016Capex.web_CAPEXProjectsByCompanyResult' to type 'System.Data.DataRowView'.`

Comment: So use `(decimal)((_2016Capex.web_CAPEXProjectsByCompanyResult)e.Item.DataItem)["..."]`